# How can you stop screen rotation on a Playbook using PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, screen-orientation, blackberry-playbook, zepto

I've found solutions to this for iOS and Android, but I can't find one for the Playbook. Is there a way to use PhoneGap or Zepto to lock the screen into portrait orientation on Playbook, and if so, how?

I've tried using the command `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />` in config.xml, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by following steps, if you are using Web Works SDK.

1. Browse to the "device_templates" directory of BlackBerry WebWorks
   SDK.  This directory is typically found in
   "[DRIVE]:\InstallDir\BlackBerry WebWorks Packager\device_templates"
2. Open the "Widget.java" file found in this directory in a text

   editor.
3. Make the below changes in the Widget.java file. The
       //MODIFIED CODE indicates the changes done

   public Widget(WidgetConfig wConfig) {

   ```
               _wConfig = wConfig;
               initialize();

               int directions = net.rim.device.api.system.Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT;    net.rim.device.api.ui.Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(directions);

               // Create PageManager
               PageManager pageManager = new PageManager(this, (WidgetConfigImpl) _wConfig);

               // push screen
               WidgetScreen wScreen = new BrowserFieldScreen(this, pageManager);
               pageManager.pushScreens((BrowserFieldScreen)wScreen);
           }
   ```